# Fetching data via API. On pagination next page I fetch the data (showing in console log) but it won't render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am fetching the data It will show the first 20 characters and render them to the UI but on the second page it only fetch the new data but it does not update on the UI.

I want to for every new page call the API and get the new data. The offsets add up for every page so I won't get the same data. That works fine. Only the rendering part does not work.

I am new to React.

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import md5 from 'md5';
import {Table,Button, Space} from 'antd';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import ReactPaginate from 'react-paginate';
const Container = styled.div`
padding: 20px;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vw;
 img{
   width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
 }
`;
// Public API key
const API_KEY = 'ecad4b21d4f7ac3013edd36c80e8e28b'
const PRIVATE_KEY = '28c291f38b55ed4e4d66f3b8cea8b7f946f700f0'
function App() {
 
  const [loadingData, setLoadingData] = useState(true);
  const[data,setData] = useState([]);
  const [perPage] = useState(10);
  const [pageCount, setPageCount] = useState(0);
  const hash = md5(API_KEY + PRIVATE_KEY);
  const [limit] = useState(20);
  const [offset, setOffset] = useState(0);
  const URL = `https://gateway.marvel.com:443/v1/public/characters?orderBy=name&apikey=ecad4b21d4f7ac3013edd36c80e8e28b&hash=${hash}&${new URLSearchParams({
    limit,
    offset
  
  })}`;
useEffect(() => {
  getData()
}, [offset]);
const getData = async() => {
  const res = await axios.get(URL);
  const data = await res.data.data.results;
     console.log(data)
    // total characters  
      const total = res.data.data.total
      console.log(total)
      setPageCount(Math.ceil(total / limit));
  
      
    //  Split data to 10
     const slice = data.slice(offset, offset + perPage)
    // Loop trhoguh sliced data
   const postData = slice.map(item => 
   <div key={item.id}>
    <p>{item.name}</p>
    <img src={item.thumbnailUrl} alt=""/>
    </div>)
    // Set data to state
    setData(postData)
    // Count page
}
console.log("this is offset", offset)
// Updating offet by one
const handlePageClick = async(e) => {
  const selectedPage = e.selected;
  const offsetData = selectedPage * limit;
  setOffset(offsetData);
  console.log(selectedPage);
  console.log(offsetData);
 
};
return (
  <div className="App">
    {data}
     <ReactPaginate
                  previousLabel={"prev"}
                  nextLabel={"next"}
                  breakLabel={"..."}
                  breakClassName={"break-me"}
                  pageCount={pageCount}
                  marginPagesDisplayed={2}
                  pageRangeDisplayed={5}
                  onPageChange={handlePageClick}
                  containerClassName={"pagination"}
                  subContainerClassName={"pages pagination"}
                  activeClassName={"active"}/>
  </div>
);
}
export default App;
```

Comment: I have also called the getData() in. the handlePageClick but nothing changed